# How should we go about allowing individual users of our web app to connect to their own DocuSign account?

Tags: docusignapi

For context, we are currently developing a DocuSign integration on our DMS web app product. So far what we have done is that the web app's admin (we assume this would be someone like our customer's IT) can set up the integration by entering API Account ID, Integration Key, Secret Key, Access Token & Refresh Token. All these information was taken/generated using a DocuSign admin account. With this, we see that any user using the DMS can send out signing requests (via API) without logging in to their own DocuSign account.

However, we realised this means that all signing requests will be sent using the common DocuSign admin account, i.e. the envelopes originate from the admin account and all signed documents also stored in the DocuSign admin account. This is not what we want as the DocuSign admin can see confidential signed documents.

I'm quite confused and would like to seek advise on how should we go about this? Ideally, it is that User A of the DMS can associate his DocuSign account with his DMS account. So that when User A sends out the signing request from our DMS, the signer receives the email from DocuSign showing it is from that user instead of the common admin account.

Also, it looks like the go-live process would have to take place for each customer that is using our DMS? Does it mean like each customer need to have their DocuSign developer account so that the integration key can get promoted to production environment? Or am I in the wrong direction & should look at Partner Integration as ISV?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please upvote and check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @LarryK , may I know if we have this set up, does it mean the user with any DocuSign plan (e.g. Standard plan) can connect their DocuSign account? Or must it be of a specific tier and above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DMS system is a SAAS system, then you can have 1 integration key (client id) for your integration with DocuSign. In other words, your individual customers would NOT have their own integration keys, secrets, etc.

One integration key is the best, if your application's architecture can support it. To do so, you'll want to have one or just a few Redirect URIs to enable your users (who also have DocuSign accounts) to authenticate with DocuSign.

Your app then stores the resulting access token, refresh token, and expiration date for each of your users who have authenticated with DocuSign.
This way, as you say, when your users send out an envelope for signing, it will belong to their own DocuSign account, and will show them as the sender.

When your customer wants to send via DocuSign, your app checks the expiration date for the person's access token. If the access token has expired, then use the refresh token to get a new access token and a new refresh token.

The refresh token is stored in your app's non-volatile storage (encrypted is best) so you can use it days or weeks later for the user. That way they don't have to re-authenticate with DocuSign. For this case, use scopes `signature%20extended`

For the account_id info, use the user's default account and enable them to switch to another account if they wish.

More information:

- [Getting started for ISVs](https://developers.docusign.com/partner/integration-guide/getting-started-isv/)
- [API integration guidelines](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/api-guidelines/)

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for your reply. May I know if we have this set up, does it mean the user with any DocuSign plan (e.g. Standard plan) can connect their DocuSign account? Or must it be of a specific tier and above?

Comment: I believe, but am not certain, that any DocuSign account can authenticate/use with a 3rd party app (an app that is not provided by DocuSign). Different account types have different feature sets. Eg some accounts won't support embedded sending.